# RingCentral REST API Correct method of posting data?

Tags: php, json, rest, api, ringcentral

I'm trying to send a request to the RingCentral API to trigger an SMS message to be sent. I've read the documentation and it appears as though I'm posting all of the data in the correct format but I'm getting an error of "Unsupported Media Type".

Does anyone see anything wrong with my code, or is do any of you guys have experience with this API?

```
$data = array("from" => "+10000000000", "to" => "+100000000", "text" => "test_sms_message");                                                                    
    $data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                                                                                                                   
    $ch = curl_init('https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/sms');                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer ".$auth_token;
    $headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($result);
```

Comment: I know nothing about this API but most likely you mean `Content-Type: application/json`.  The `Accept` header doesn't do anything when you're sending a request (at least if the API is following the HTTP spec correctly)

Comment: That was actually it! Thank you, I spent an awful long time tinkering with this to try and get it right! I really apprecite your help.

Comment: For reference, the official RingCentral PHP SDK is here https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-php and there is an unofficial community SDK here https://github.com/grokify/ringcentral-sdk-php-lite

Answer (score 0):

So I'm going to post an answer to my own question and include the entire code I used. This code will allow you to get an authorization token first and then use that token to send a request to the RingCentral REST API. I couldn't find a working PHP example anywhere online so I'm sure this will help someone else out there.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/oauth/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=+1XXXXXXXXX&password=XXXXXXXXX&extension=XXX&grant_type=password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "XXXXXXXXXXXX" . ":" . "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$decoded_results = json_decode($result, true);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
   echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
curl_close ($ch);
$auth_token = $decoded_results['access_token'];
// LINE BREAK


$data_string = '{"to": [{"phoneNumber": "+INSERTNUMBER"}],"from": {"phoneNumber": "+INSERTNUMBER}"},"text": "Test SMS message from Platform server"}';                                                                                                                                                                                   
$ch = curl_init('https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/sms');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer ".$auth_token;
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
```